# IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I am using multi-threading in java for my program.
I have run thread successfully but when I am using `Thread.wait()`, it is throwing `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`.
How can I make a thread wait until it will be notified?

Comment: Thread.wait() does not exist, it might be this.wait()

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You need to be in a `synchronized` block of the object you want to wait on in order for `Object.wait()` to work.

Also, I recommend looking at the concurrency packages instead of the old school threading packages. They are safer and way [easier to work with](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

I assumed you meant `Object.wait()` as your exception is what happens when you try to gain access without holding the objects lock.

Comment: good catch. i assumed he meant Object.wait() and called from a thread

Comment: A synchronized block on the object that you are waiting on.  Care to edit this answer to make that a little more clear?  Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

`wait` is defined in `Object`, and not it `Thread`. The monitor on `Thread` is a little unpredictable.

Although all Java objects have monitors, it is generally better to have a dedicated lock:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

You can get slightly easier to read diagnostics, at a small memory cost (about 2K per process) by using a named class:

```
private static final class Lock { }
private final Object lock = new Lock();
```

In order to `wait` or `notify`/`notifyAll` an object, you need to be holding the lock with the `synchronized` statement. Also, you will need a `while` loop to check for the wakeup condition (find a good text on threading to explain why).

```
synchronized (lock) {
    while (!isWakeupNeeded()) {
        lock.wait();
    }
}
```

To notify:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    makeWakeupNeeded();
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

It is well worth getting to understand both Java language and `java.util.concurrent.locks` locks (and `java.util.concurrent.atomic`) when getting into multithreading. But use `java.util.concurrent` data structures whenever you can.

Comment: I've never understood how this works, given that the wait and notify are both in synchronized blocks on the same object (lock). Since the wait thread is in the block, shouldn't that make the notify thread block on the "synchronized (lock)" line?

Comment: @Brent212 For any method other than `wait`, yes you'd never get to `notify`. However, in the API docs for `Object.wait`, "The thread releases ownership of this monitor". So whilst in `wait` it's as if it is outside of the enclosing `synchronized` blocks (for the same object, may be multiple `synchronized` blocks on the same object).

Answer (score 26):

I know this thread is almost 2 years old but still need to close this since I also came to this Q/A session with same issue...

Please read this definition of illegalMonitorException again and again...

**IllegalMonitorException is thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.**

This line again and again says, IllegalMonitorException comes when one of the 2 situation occurs....

1> wait on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

2> notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

Some might have got their answers... who all doesn't, then please check 2 statements....

**synchronized (object)**

**object.wait()**

If both **object** are same... then no illegalMonitorException can come.

Now again read the IllegalMonitorException definition and you wont forget it again...

Comment: Actually, that doesnt work. I have tried it. I create a Runnable, lock on it (using synchronized block) and inside that block I run Runnable on the UI-thread (Android) and after that I do myRunnable.wait(), and I still get the exception.

Comment: Excelente explanation!! I was doing wait() without specifying the object, so it took the instance, and synchronicing on another object. Now I am using otherObject.wait() and it works!

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comments it sounds like you are doing something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() { // do stuff }});

thread.start();
...
thread.wait();
```

There are three problems.

1. As others have said, `obj.wait()` can only be called if the current thread holds the primitive lock / mutex for `obj`.  If the current thread does not hold the lock, you get the exception you are seeing.
2. The `thread.wait()` call does not do what you seem to be expecting it to do.  Specifically, `thread.wait()` **does not** cause the nominated thread to wait.  Rather it causes *the current thread* to wait until some other thread calls `thread.notify()` or `thread.notifyAll()`.

   There is actually no safe way to force a `Thread` instance to pause if it doesn't want to.  (The nearest that Java has to this is the deprecated `Thread.suspend()` method, but that method is inherently unsafe, as is explained in the Javadoc.)

   If you want the newly started `Thread` to pause, the best way to do it is to create a `CountdownLatch` instance and have the thread call `await()` on the latch to pause itself.  The main thread would then call `countDown()` on the latch to let the paused thread continue.
3. Orthogonal to the previous points, using a `Thread` object as a lock / mutex may cause problems.  For example, the javadoc for `Thread::join` says:

   > This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted code, we're kind of working in the dark.  What are the details of the exception?

**Are you calling Thread.wait() from within the thread, or outside it?**

I ask this because according to the javadoc for IllegalMonitorStateException, it is:

> *Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.*

To clarify this answer, this call to wait on a thread also throws IllegalMonitorStateException, despite being called from within a synchronized block:

```
     private static final class Lock { }
     private final Object lock = new Lock();

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker();
        System.out.println ("Starting worker");
        worker.start();
        System.out.println ("Worker started - telling it to wait");
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                worker.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            String msg = "InterruptedException: [" + e1.getLocalizedMessage() + "]";
            System.out.println (msg);
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println ("Worker done waiting, we're now waiting for it by joining");
        try {
            worker.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }

    }
```

Comment: @CPerkins: I think you're confusing the execution thread and the object which is the target of `wait()`.

Comment: @Robert - Perhaps I am, but I don't think so.  If you start a Thread instance, and then ask it to wait, you'll get an IllegalMonitorStateException, which is what I was attempting to describe.

Comment: Are you talking about the `worker.wait()` line? Then you should be synchronizing on the worker, not on the lock.

Answer (score 2):

In order to deal with the IllegalMonitorStateException, you must verify that all invocations of the wait, notify and notifyAll methods are taking place only when the calling **thread owns the appropriate monitor**. The most simple solution is to enclose these calls inside synchronized blocks. The synchronization object that shall be invoked in the synchronized statement is the one whose monitor must be acquired.

Here is the simple example for to understand the concept of monitor

```
public class SimpleMonitorState {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        SimpleMonitorState t = new SimpleMonitorState();
        SimpleRunnable m = new SimpleRunnable(t);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m);
        t1.start();
        t.call();

    }

    public void call() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            wait();
            System.out.println("Single by Threads ");
        }
    }

}

class SimpleRunnable implements Runnable {

    SimpleMonitorState t;

    SimpleRunnable(SimpleMonitorState t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            // Sleep
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            synchronized (this.t) {
                this.t.notify();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread.wait() call make sense inside a code that synchronizes on Thread.class object. I don't think it's what you meant.
You ask

> How can I make a thread wait until it will be notified?

You can make only your current thread wait. Any other thread can be only gently asked to wait, if it agree.
If you want to wait for some condition, you need a lock object - Thread.class object is a very bad choice - it is a singleton AFAIK so synchronizing on it (except for Thread static methods) is dangerous.
Details for synchronization and waiting are already explained by Tom Hawtin.
`java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` means you are trying to wait on object on which you are not synchronized - it's illegal to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help somebody else out or not but this was the key part to fix my problem in user "Tom Hawtin - tacklin"'s answer above:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    makeWakeupNeeded();
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Just the fact that the "lock" is passed as an argument in synchronized() and it is also used in "lock".notifyAll();

Once I made it in those 2 places I got it working

Answer (score 0):

I received a `IllegalMonitorStateException` while trying to wake up a thread in / from a different `class` / thread. In `java 8` you can use the [`lock` features of the new Concurrency API](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/) **instead** of `synchronized` functions.

I was already storing objects for `asynchronous` websocket transactions in a `WeakHashMap`. The solution in my case was to also [store a `lock` object in a `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176468/java-shared-condition-between-classes-throws-illegalmonitorstateexception-null) for `synchronous` replies. **Note** the `condition.await` (not `.wait`).

To handle the multi threading I used a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` to create a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--).

Answer (score 0):

Those who are using Java 7.0 or below version can refer the code which I used here and it works.

```
public class WaitTest {

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void waitHere(long waitTime) {
        System.out.println("wait started...");
        lock.lock();
        try {
            condition.await(waitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("wait ends here...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code
        new WaitTest().waitHere(10);
        //Your Code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling wait()/notify() on object, it needs to be inside synchronized block. So first you have to take lock on object then would be possible to call these function.

```
synchronized(obj)
{
   obj.wait()
}
```

For detailed explanation:
https://dzone.com/articles/multithreading-java-and-interviewspart-2

Answer (score 0):

wait(), notify() and notifyAll() methods should only be called in **syncronized contexts**.

For example, in a syncronized block:

```
syncronized (obj) {
        obj.wait();
}
```

Or, in a syncronized method:

```
syncronized static void myMethod() {
        wait();
}
```