# Getting IllegalMonitorStateException while using wait() in Job scheduler

Tags: java, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I'm working on a Java RMI based project which has `Client-->Job Scheduler--> Server structure`.

I have two methods in Job scheduler class as given below. Commenting explains the purpose of each line of code.

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Job> jobQueue;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ComputeServerRef> serverQueue;    
private final Object lock = new Object();
   /**
     * Accepts newly generated job from client and schedule it with idle Compute
     * Server or queue it in JobQueue depending on the availability of idle 
     * Compute Server in serverQueue.
     *
     * @param  job Job object 
     * 
     * @exception  RemoteException
     *     Thrown if any remote remote error occurred.
     */
    public Job acceptJob(Job job) throws RemoteException
    {           
        // Report a "Job scheduled" to all Loggers.        
        eventGenerator.reportEvent(new JobSchedulerEvent 
                ("Job "+job.getJobName()+" scheduled"));
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                if (!serverQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    // If serverQueue is not empty then get one server from it,   
                    // remove it from the server queue and assign it a new job. 
                    ComputeServerRef csr = serverQueue.poll();
                    try
                    {                       
                        job = csr.performJob(job);                      
                        updateServerStatus(csr);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch(RemoteException re)
                    {                                               
                        continue;
                    }                                   
                }   
                else
                {           
                    jobQueue.add(job);  
                    try{
                        Thread.currentThread().wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
                    }               
                    // Check if it's the turn of current thread's job. 
                    // If not then goto wait();
                    while (!jobQueue.peek().getJobName().equals(job.getJobName()))
                    {
                        try{
                            Thread.currentThread().wait();
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
                        }                   
                    }               
                    job=jobQueue.poll();                    
                }
            }
        }
        return job;
    }   

    /**
     * Adds newly started compute server to serverQueue
     *
     * @param  csr reference of the remote object ComputeServer.
     * 
     * @exception RemoteException
     *            Thrown if any remote remote error occurred
     */
    public void updateServerStatus(ComputeServerRef csr)throws RemoteException
    {       
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            serverQueue.add(csr);    
            Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting IllegalMonitorStateException at the first call to `wait()` method in `acceptJob()`. Any idea, how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Jiten

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is it logically correct for your application, but  changing

```
Thread.currentThread().wait();
```

to

```
lock.wait();
```

should make the exception not to be thrown. Please, feedback.

EDIT:

in both places, and also change

```
Thread.currentThread().notifyAll();
```

EDIT^2:

for explanation look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java.html)

in short:

```
synchronized(object) {                        //1
   object.{wait(),notify(),notifyAll()};      //2
}
```

object from line 1 must be the **same** object as the one in line 2, [because](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) if they are not the same IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

where *owning the monitor* would mean that it needs to be inside the synchronized block (as shown in lines 1,2)

Comment: if u did as described and posted all the relevant code, you should not get IllegalMonitorStateException. What exactly do you mean by "it did not work" - is it not giving the expexted results or is it throwing exception - if so, code and stacktrace, pls

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized(lock) {
    Thread.currentThread().wait();
}
```

You are getting exception because, you can only call `wait` upon the object that you have locked.. Here you have lock on the object `lock`.. So wait should be called on lock..

so, you should change your `wait` call to `lock.wait()`

```
synchronized(lock) {
        lock.wait();
}
```

Same case is with `notify`, you need to call it on the object you have `locked`..

Comment: @JitenPatel.. What problem is coming?? It should work if you have called wait on locked object.