# IllegalMonitorStateException - wait

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Object obj = new Object();

    obj.wait();
    obj.notify();

}
```

please I didn't understand why it throws  java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException??

Comment: by reading the documentation the Truth will be revealed to you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, found the reason.

Comment: when I add this :

    `synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
  obj.wait();
  obj.notify();
   }`

it give me the same exception.

Comment: Not a valid question to ask here , it should have been asked so many times

Comment: of course it gives you the same exception, as documented

Comment: Sorry, my duplicate question was _not_ the right one.  This is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1537400/179850

Answer (score 3):

In order to wait on or notify on an object, [you must be in a synchronized block locking on the object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1537133/1424875)

The following code will work (run but not do anything as there are no threads to synchronize):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Object obj = new Object();
    synchronized(obj){
        obj.wait();
        obj.notify();
    }
}
```