# Make a blocking thread for message queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a simple server-client application. I'm handling the message queue this way (`class MessageQueue`):

```
private Vector<String> messages;
//Runs from any thread
public void add(String message) {
    synchronized(messages) {
      messages.add(message);
      //This is only way to unstuck messages.wait()
      messages.notifyAll();
    }
}
//Runs from special thread
private void readQueue() {
    Log.debug("Waiting for messages to send.");
    while(run) {
        synchronized(messages) {
          //STUCK HERE!
          try {messages.wait();}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          //send messages
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

I designed the code using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289463/607407), but it's wrong or I haven't interpreted it correctly. Here's what happens:

1. Thread `readQueue` starts.
2. Thread `readQueue` blocks `messages` by `synchronized` block.
3. Thread `readQueue` blocks itself on `messages.wait()`.
4. Another thread calls `add("...")` method.
5. Another thread gets stuck on `synchronized` block.

The `messages.notifyAll()` can never be called. Of course, originally, before searching, I was trying to do this:

```
//Runs from special thread
private void readQueue() {
    Log.debug("Waiting for messages to send.");
    while(run) {
        //Wait before getting noticed of new message
        try {messages.wait();}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        //Block messages, read them, clear them
        synchronized(messages) {
          //send messages
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

This throws [illegal monitor exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1537116/607407), which forces me to put `wait` into `synchronized` - and we're just where we begun - stuck.

Comment: You may find [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) useful.

Comment: I guess I would. But I still wonder how this stuff works together.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I copied your code, and I don't see any thread getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while noone has given me a solution I've been testing and thinking. As [Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23290838/607407) has pointed out, `wait` call releases the variable in current `synchronized` block. But there is more to it.
Java is smart enough to prevent conflicts and will not release the `synchronised` of other operations are performed on the variable in the block.

All I had to do was putting the `wait` and the `while` that sends messages into different `synchronized` blocks.
This is **correct code** that works:

```
private void readQueue() {
    Log.debug("Waiting for messages to send.");
    while(run) {
        //Calling isEmpty here is a little unsafe but I decided that I don't care
        if(messages.isEmpty()) {
          synchronized(messages) {
            Log.debug("Getting STUCK!");
            //After calling wait, the messages is released, just as expected
            try {messages.wait();}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          }
        }
        //The sending
        synchronized(messages) {
          //send messages
        }
    }
}
```

It looks a little silly, but it makes sense. Consider the old, **wrong code** and a scenario:

```
//Runs from special thread
private void readQueue() {
    while(run) {
        synchronized(messages) {
          //STUCK HERE!
          try {messages.wait();}catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          //send messages
          ...
        }
    }
}
private void evil() {
    synchronized(messages) {
       messages.notify();
       messages.clear(); 
    }
}
```

1. `readQueue` thread enters `synchronized` block
2. `readQueue` thread calls `messages.wait()` and releases `messages`
3. Another thread runs `evil()`
4. Evil calls notify and allows `readQueue` to continue
5. At this moment, two `synchronized` blocks are operating on `messages`

I wonder how exactly is the checking implemented and what actions are allowed. I have no proof (e.g. I have found nothing about this in docs) for this but the fact that the first code works for me and the second does not.

Comment: That should be something like: 4. and allows readQueue to continue' **after** it cleared the messages and releases the lock. 5a readQueue takes the messages-lock 5b. At this moment only readQueue operates on messages (which is probably still empty)

Comment: See my example with the guarding loop.

Comment: @Ishtar No. `wait` does not re-initialise the lock. And `notify` was called before `clear` and is granted to unlock the blocking `wait`. However, java will not let that happen.

Comment: @TomášZato Yes! Wait does re-initialise the lock. 'Thread t performs n lock actions on m' [17.2.1 item 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1). It is granted after the monitor is unlocked, thus after the call to clear. 'Notice, however, that u's lock actions upon resumption cannot succeed **until** some time after **t fully unlocks the monitor** for m.' See 17.2.2 bullet two.

Answer (score 0):

A thread can't be stuck on the `add` method, since `messages.wait()` releases the object monitor. That way when your special thread is `wait()`ing, other threads are free to enter the synchronized block in `add()` (but one at a time only).

To prevent your "evil" example, you need a guarding while loop. If the consumer thread is notified, but `messages` is emptied, it will notice that in the while loop and `wait()` again.

```
while(running) {
    synchronized(messages) {
        while(messages.isEmpty())  // Guard against evilness
           try { messages.wait() } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        // If we get here, messages can't be empty ever
        sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Edit:
The timeline is as follows, Thread1 is producer, Thread2 is consumer.

```
Thread1 enters synchronized block.
Thread1 adds an item to messages.
Thread1 calls notify.
Thread1 exits synchronized block.
Thread2 enters synchronized block.
Thread2 checks to see if there are messages, and there are.
Thread2 proceeds to send message.
Thread2 exits synchronized block.
```

OR

```
Thread2 enters synchronized block.
Thread2 checks to see if there are messages, but there aren't any.
Thread2 waits() and releases the monitor.
Thread1 enters synchronized block.
Thread1 adds an item to messages.
Thread1 calls notify. (Thread2 is released from wait(), but can't run yet since it needs to acquire the monitor.
Thread1 exits synchronized block.
Thread2 acquires the monitor.
Thread2 checks the loop and notices there is a message.
Thread2 sends the message.
Thread2 exits the synchronized block.
```

Comment: Could you please make a sample code to prove me wrong? I have planted a lot of debug messages to track where is what stuck and I can see that things happen as I describe them.
Also, two parallel `synchronized` blocks would be running if the things are as you say. (At the moment of `notify` call).

Comment: Two synchronized blocks (on the same object monitor) can't be running at the same time. It's not possible.

Comment: No, it's not. That's why my original code got stuck. Because it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible for two threads to run at the same time in a synchronized block. My example code however works correctly and the guard loop prevents your evilness (of emptying the vector). However, just because the `wait()` is released doesn't mean that the thread is free to run, it still needs to reacquire the monitor (since it's still in the synchronized block). It will run after the other thread has freed the monitor by exiting its synchronized block.

Comment: You owe me +25 points for using this much time to educate you :)