# Can I add a binary file to a String based server message queue?

Tags: java, file, sockets

I have a multi-threaded client-server application that uses `Vector<String>` as a [queue of messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23290543/607407) to send.

I need, however, to send a file using this application. In C++ I would not really worry, but in Java I'm a little confused when converting anything to string.

Java has 2 byte characters. When you see Java string in HEX, it's usually like:

```
00XX 00XX 00XX 00XX
```

Unless some Unicode characters are present.

Java also uses Big endian.

These facts make me unsure, whether - and eventually how - to add the file into the queue. Preferred format of the file would be:

```
-- Headers --
2 bytes  Size of the block (excluding header, which means first four bytes)
2 bytes  Data type (text message/file)
-- End of headers --
2 bytes  Internal file ID (to avoid referring by filenames)
2 bytes  Length of filename
X bytes  Filename
X bytes  Data
```

You can see I'm already using 2 bytes for all numbers to avoid some horrible operations required when getting 2 numbers out of one char.

But I have really no idea how to add the file data correctly. For numbers, I assume this would do:

```
StringBuilder packetData = new StringBuilder();
packetData.append((char) packetSize);
packetData.append((char) PacketType.BINARY.ordinal()); //Just convert enum constant to number
```

But file is really a problem. If I have also described anything wrongly regarding the Java data types please correct me - I'm a beginner.

Comment: Perhaps you can base64-encode the file's binary representation.

Comment: Unfortunately, base64 significantly increases file size. Something you want to avoid when sending files over network.

Comment: The answer is *yes, but you really shouldn't*. If sending files is a new requirement, then reworking the queue system to either be more flexible in message type or handle the files out of band is in order.

Comment: That might be true, however the queue system is not here to decide what data is what. So all I can do is to abbadon this question and post question: *How to convert string into a byte array* and *How to send a byte array through socket*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it **have** to send only `String`s? I think if it does then you really need to encode it using `base64` or similar. The best approach overall would probably be to send it as raw `bytes`. Depending on how difficult it would be to `refactor` your code to support `byte array`s instead of just `String`s, that may be worth doing.

To answer your `String` question I just saw pop up in the comments, there's a `getBytes` method on a `String`.

For the socket question, see:
[Java sending and receiving file (byte[]) over sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520911/java-sending-and-receiving-file-byte-over-sockets)

Comment: Ok, I agree with you - sending byte arrays makes more sense and will be easier to understand for me.