# Android String if-statement

Tags: java, android, string

I have a if-statement in the start of my app

```
    if (ready.equals("yes")){
...
}
```

and later on my code I have

```
ready="yes";
```

but the if statement is never called, why?
The ready="yes"; is called from a background thread, is that why?

```
    public void DownloadFromUrl(final String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://xxxxxxx");
            File file = new File(PATH + fileName);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
                    /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                    /*
                     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                     */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

                    /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.e("Ready or not", ready);
            ready="yes";
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                    + " sec");
            Log.e("Ready or not", ready);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

    }
    }).start();
```

Comment: You might want to add some more context as to where in your program the ready variable is set (in onCreate, in a  thread, in a onClick, etc.)

Comment: Would be good if you can post more of your code

Comment: updated, the check for the if-statement is nothing special, it is just called in the begining of the onCreate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong. If you're saying that your code looks like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run()
                            {
                                // thread code
                                if (ready.equals("yes")) {
                                    // handler code
                                }
                                // more thread code
                            }).start();

// later on...
ready = "yes";
```

And you're asking why `ready = "yes"` doesn't execute before `if (ready.equals("yes"))`, then that's because **multiple threads aren't guaranteed to execute in a certain order**. If you want to wait until `ready.equals("yes")` before you execute the `if` statement, then you have to use the `Object.wait()` and `Object.notifyAll()` methods:

```
// this is a field
private Object waitOnThis = new Object();

new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run()
                            {
                                // thread code
                                waitOnThis.wait(); // blocks until notify / notifyAll is called on waitOnThis
                                // by this point ready.equals("yes")
                                if (ready.equals("yes")) {
                                    // handler code
                                }
                                // more thread code
                            }).start();

// later on...
ready = "yes";
waitOnThis.notifyAll(); // unblocks threads waiting on waitOnThis
```

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Be sure to wrap each of the code fragments above in a `synchronized (waitOnThis)` block, or else you'll get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: yeah but the ready="yes" will ALWAYS be called after the if-statement since it runs in the background, seperate from the main activity and is called about 2-3 seconds AFTER the if-part is checked

Comment: May I suggest that anytime you use `equals` with a constant, put the constant on the left: `"yes".equals(ready)`. This way you always avoid `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: acually the (ready.equals("yes")) was in onCreate/a void but I tried it your way but I get unhandled.exception on  waitOnThis.wait();

Comment: @EmilioGaines Whoops, it looks like you need to be in a [synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1537133/4077294) block for `Object.wait()` to work. Try wrapping everything in a `synchronized (waitOnThis)` block (and if that happens in `DownloadFromUrl`, add `synchronized` there as well).

Answer (score 0):

`Application`'s `OnCreate` will only be called once at the beginning when the app is created.

Consider using callback if you want to notify that the download has finished.