# Exception in java for wait() method

Tags: java

```
public class Bees {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Bees().go();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("thrown to main" + e);
        }
    }

    synchronized void go() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        t1.start();
        System.out.print("1 ");
        t1.wait(5000);
        System.out.print("2 ");
    }
}
```

Output of this Program is :

```
1 thrown to main
```

I am not getting why this `thrown to main` came over here.

Comment: may be you should have check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call

Comment: Do you understand what the `wait()` method does?

Comment: @Kayaman Its pleasure if you give me some idea about wait() method.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use it as some sort of general pause method. If you're not familiar with the `wait()/notify()` mechanism, I recommend doing a search here, there are plenty of great explanations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` because the object you are calling `wait()` on (`t1`) does not own the synchronization lock.

Note that, when you declare a method as `synchronized`, the lock owner for that method is the current object (your instance of `Bees` in that case). If you want to call `wait()` on `t1`, you need to synchronize on `t1`:

```
...
    Thread t1 = new Thread();
    synchronized(t1) {
        t1.start();
        System.out.print("1 ");
        t1.wait(5000);
    }
...
```

On a side note, when catching an exception, you should always include the exception itself to the log output, at least like

```
...
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("thrown to main" + e);
}
...
```

Otherwise you might miss important information (such as **which** exception was actually thrown).

See also [The Java™ Tutorials: Synchronization.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `wait` from inside `synchronized` block. The current thread should obtain the object's monitor before it waits.

Copied from [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

```
synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```