# Why Java compiler does not trace if object monitor is properly handled

Tags: java, synchronized, runtimeexception

In the following snippet

```
synchronized(myMonitorObject)
  try{
    myMonitorObject.wait();
  } catch(InterruptedException e){...}
}
```

if the first line is omitted why the compiler does not object but instead IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown?

Comment: Because the monitor can be acquired outside of current file. Moreover, it can be acquired indirectly by calling some outside procedure. Compiler cannot detect all situations correctly. Therefore, the check is made in run time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
public void m1(Object lock) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.wait();
}
```

Should that be a compilation error?

Now consider this:

```
public void m2() throws InterruptedException {
    Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized (lock) {
        m1(lock);
    }
}
```

Should `m1` *still* be a compilation error?

The problem with making `m1` a compilation error (as you seems to be suggesting) is that what it is doing is not necessarily incorrect.  In fact, it is impossible to for the compiler to reliably distinguish correct from incorrect without being conservative.  The analogies are:

- The compiler does not treat code that will trigger an NPE as a compilation error.
- The compiler *does* treat the use of an uninitialized local variable as an error.   However, Java's strict *definite assignment* rules mean that some cases where a variable would actually be initialized are treated as errors.