# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException when condition.wait

Tags: java

```
private static volatile AtomicInteger blockClientCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

private static Object lock = new Object();

private static Lock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

private static Condition condition = reentrantLock.newCondition();    

@Override
public void run() {
    Random random = new Random(this.hashCode());
    while (true) {
        String request = random.nextInt(10) + "" + IOUtil.operators[random.nextInt(4)] + (random.nextInt(10) + 1);
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " send request：" + request);
        if (socketConnect()) {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                blockClientCount.incrementAndGet();

                reentrantLock.lock();
                try {
                    while (blockClientCount.get() % IOUtil.CLIENNT_NUM != 0) {
                        /**
                         * TODO java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
                         */
                        condition.wait();
                    }
                    condition.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    reentrantLock.unlock();
                }

                // synchronized (lock) {
                // while (blockClientCount.get() % IOUtil.CLIENNT_NUM != 0)
                // {
                // lock.wait();
                // }
                // lock.notifyAll();
                // }
                out.println(request);
                String response = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " accept response：" + response);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                IOUtil.close(in);
                IOUtil.close(out);
            }
        }
        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " was interrupted and stop");
            IOUtil.close(socket);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

the java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException will happen when i use ReentrantLock to wait, but it works well when i use synchronized , i can'not explain it.
The reason is that reentrantLock is unlock before condition.wait(),but i don't know why.
if someone can help me,i have submit the code to https://github.com/shanhm1991/demo_io.git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call)

Comment: @VinceEmigh That is not a duplicate of this specific problem, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're calling the wrong method. You should call `await()` rather than `wait()` on a `Condition` object:

```
reentrantLock.lock();
try {
    condition.await();
} finally {
    reentrantLock.unlock();
}
```

You're currently calling `wait` which is the `Object.wait()` method, which requires you to be synchronized on the object that you are calling it on. But that's not what you want, you want the specific wait functionality of the `Condition` class, and that is only available through the method `await`.